# CSS3 animation stay at end state for 3 seconds

Tags: css, animation, delay

When doing CSS3 animation, is it possible to stay at the end of the animation for a few seconds and then go back to the original state?

I know you can make the CSS3 animation end on the last frame, or go back to the first frame, but I want to to pause at the last frame for a few seconds then go back to the beginning.

Thank you.

Comment: if you don't want any delay the end state should be at `100%`, if you want some delay the end state should be some middle value such as `50%`. All the remaining keyframe duration won't change the state. That's how it should be done. The exact value depends on the `animation-duration` and how long you want to delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You'll have to do some math, though, because keyframe stops are measured in percentage of total animation. Let's say your total animation should last 12 seconds -- that means your animation should be unmoving for the last 25% of the total animation time. I'll modify an example from [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) to demonstrate this.

```
div.animated {
    -webkit-animation: with_delay 12s linear 0s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: with_delay 12s linear 0s infinite; /* Standard syntax */
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes with_delay {
    0%   {background: red;}
    75%  {background: green;}
    100% {background: green;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes with_delay {
    0%   {background: red;}
    75%  {background: green;}
    100% {background: green;}
}
```

[**Here is a live demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/j5ewhw67/)

---

Note that if you don't mind the delay being at the beginning of the animation instead of the end, it's even easier. Simply specify [`animation-delay`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp) or [`transition-delay`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp) depending on which animation technique you already have implemented.

Comment: Thank you Woodrow Barlow that was an easy fix for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need a little Javascript to make it work.  You can detect the end of the animation via Javascript, run a timer, and when the timer completes you can reset and restart the animation.

Here's some references:

- [CSS Animation Callback](http://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback)
- [Restart CSS Animation](http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)